# It is not allowed to use stages more than once [Jenkins_Declarative_Pipeline]

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, build-pipeline, groovy

I am completely new to the jenkins pipeline. I'm trying to create a project with multiple stages but in my `Import` stage , I want to execute `parallel`. For each `stage` in `parallel` , I have again multiple `stages`. I'm trying the following way, but getting syntax error as `It is not allowed to use stages more than once`.Can someone correct me how to achieve this, I have tried some online resources but unable to get clear syntax.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'from build'
      }
    }
  }

    stage('Test_A') {
      parallel {
        stages("GUI") { stage("Tests_A") { steps {echo 'from A'}} stage("Archive") {echo 'from Publish' } }
        stages("API") { stage("Tests_B") {steps {echo 'from B'} } }
        stages("CLI") {  stage("Tests_C") {steps {echo 'from C'} }}

      }
    }

  }
```

I want to create something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got answer from StackOverflow and here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702811/it-is-not-allowed-to-use-stages-more-than-once-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) to the answer.

```
stage('Test') {
    parallel {
        stage("Test_A") { 
            stages {
                stage("Tests_A") { steps { echo 'from A' } } 
                stage("Archieve") { steps { echo 'from Archieve' } }
            }
        }
        stage("Test_B") {
            ...
        }

        ... and so on
    }
}
```